# Tela branca Ionic v2

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Estou fazendo um aplicativo utilizando ionic v2 e esta funcionando perfeitamente, meu problema é que quando gero para produção -> ionic cordoa build android --prod. Em alguns celulares começa a dar Tela Branca.

Alguem passou por algo parecido só quando gerado com '--prod' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

só em você esta usando em produção já era para reduzir este tempo na tela branca e seu aplicativo ter um ganho muito superior em performance.
Uma pergunta você habilitou o ***enableProdMode(); em main.ts***?

Comment: Fiz isso e funcionou. obrigado